# How do I export a Dataframe in a .csv file?(Google Colab/jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

```
df5.to_csv("C:\\Users\\624376\\Desktop\\ExportedCrimeData2015-2020.csv")
```

Tried running this line of code to save my dataframe as a CSV. But the file doesn't show up on my desktop.

Comment: Colab is Colab:
https://cyublog.com/articles/python-en/colab-pandas-three-ways-to-save-dataframe-data/